# Bad output from ffmpeg running on raw video from Wear OS device

Tags: ffmpeg, adb, wear-os

I am following [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/debugging#screenrecord) regarding capturing and converting video from a Wear OS device, and I am running into problems. I get a video and I can tell it is my screen but it seems to be warped. This should be a green check with some white text.

[image]

There is a lot of noise when I run this:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 400x400 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -i video.raw -an -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4
```

Here

```
ffmpeg version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[rawvideo @ 0x7fbcec008200] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'video.raw':
  Duration: 00:00:07.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 38566 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 400x400, 38400 kb/s, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] profile High, level 2.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] 264 - core 159 r2999 296494a - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=10 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 400x400, q=-1--1, 10 fps, 10240 tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
[rawvideo @ 0x7fbcec008200] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 70).
video.raw: corrupt input packet in stream 0
[rawvideo @ 0x7fbce980c800] Invalid buffer size, packet size 145920 < expected frame_size 480000
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
frame=   70 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      90kB time=00:00:06.70 bitrate= 110.3kbits/s speed=46.5x    
video:89kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.788509%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] frame I:4     Avg QP:15.11  size:  8077
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] frame P:26    Avg QP:12.39  size:  2159
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] frame B:40    Avg QP: 9.83  size:    40
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] consecutive B-frames: 21.4%  5.7%  4.3% 68.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] mb I  I16..4: 53.0%  3.3% 43.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] mb P  I16..4:  9.2%  2.0% 11.1%  P16..4:  2.4%  1.3%  0.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:73.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  1.5%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:98.4%  L0:24.1% L1:75.9% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] 8x8 transform intra:6.5% inter:9.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 26.1% 44.1% 43.9% inter: 0.3% 0.8% 0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] i16 v,h,dc,p: 89%  5%  5%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 10% 22% 67%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 13% 69% 10%  0%  1%  0%  5%  0%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] i8c dc,h,v,p: 59% 41%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] Weighted P-Frames: Y:30.8% UV:30.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] ref P L0: 83.0%  3.1% 13.0%  0.5%  0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbce980d400] kb/s:102.92
```

Any ideas?